# Symfony3 JMSSecurityExtraBundle Loop of redirections with isAuthenticated in access_control

Tags: jms, symfony, access-control

I use [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle) (1.6.1) with

- Symfony 3.1
- FOSUserBundle
- JMSI18nRoutingBundle
- JMSTranslationBundle

Everything works when I'm logged and try to access to login page. (403 denied exception)
But if i'm not authenticated and try to acces to login page, I have a loop of redirections.

misconfiguration ? or bug with JMSI18nRoutingBundle ? any idea ?

```
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/

        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check

        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/connect/check-facebook"
                google:             "/connect/check-google"
                twitter:            "/connect/check-twitter"
            login_path:        fos_user_security_login
            failure_path:      /connect
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: customUserProvider

        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
        anonymous: true

access_control:
    - { path: "^/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}/login$", role: "!is_Authenticated()" }
    - { path: "^/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}/register", role: "!is_Authenticated()" }
    - { path: "^/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}/resetting", role: "!is_Authenticated()" }
    - { path: "^/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}/(account|compte){1}", role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
    - { path: "^/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}/(recipe/add|recette/ajouter){1}", role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
    - { path: "^/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}/(recipe/.*/edit|recette/.*/editer){1}", role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

`is_Authenticated()` Will not suffice in this case since an `ANONYMOUS` user is automatically assigned the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` role and therefore is authenticated.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Above a one of the possible solutions you could use to prevent the loop.